# Java adding values to an array to an other class

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to read doubles from a file and put them in an array.There are two arrays I have made.The first double would be in first array and the second would be in second array third in first and so on...
But I have to use a separate class for this purpose(to store arrays).

Here is the code which is supposed to ask for user to choose a file which should be read and then put the doubles in arrays but its not working and I don't know why...

```
package projectApplicationDevelopment;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

import ui.UIAuxiliaryMethods;

public class NumRow {
    static int i=0;
    public NumRow() {
        UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput();       
    }

    public NumRow(int numOfElementsOfDataSet) {
        this.i=numOfElementsOfDataSet;
    }

    static double fat=0;
    static double protien=0;
    static double [] fatContent=new double[i];
    static double [] protienContent=new double[i];

    static void storeDoublesAndPrintMaxMin() {
       Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

       int counter=0;
       while(in.hasNext()) {
           fat=in.nextDouble();
           protien=in.nextDouble();
           fatContent[counter]=fat;
           protienContent[counter]=protien;
           counter++;
       }
       Arrays.sort(fatContent);
       double max_fat = fatContent[fatContent.length - 1];
       double min_fat = fatContent[0];

       Arrays.sort(protienContent);
       double max_Protien = protienContent[protienContent.length - 1];
       double min_Protien = protienContent[0];

       System.out.println("The maximum fat in this file was"+max_fat);
       System.out.println("The minimum fat in this file was"+min_fat);
       System.out.println("The maximum Protien in this file was"+max_Protien);
       System.out.println("The maximum Protien in this file was"+min_Protien);  
   }
```

It is also supposed to print max and min values of array.
I am a beginner to Java so I understand my code might look stupid to you.
Thnaks and help is highly appreciated.

Comment: please define "it's not working"! What error messages or undesirable output do you get?

Comment: This is what I get:
    "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:     -1
 at projectApplicationDevelopment.NumRow.storeDoublesAndPrintMaxMin(NumRow.java:34)
 at projectApplicationDevelopment.CallingClass.start(CallingClass.java:21)
 at projectApplicationDevelopment.CallingClass.main(CallingClass.java:26)"

I call this class from my main class using "NumRow.storeDoublesAndPrintMaxMin();"

Comment: What's the code on `NumRow` line 34? You get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, if you google it you'll see that you're specifying an out of bounds index to and array. So `int[] a=new int[2]` -> `int[4]` calls an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you declared `i` as 0 and then you are doing

```
static double [] fatContent=new double[i];
static double [] protienContent=new double[i];
```

this is not Excel, the real length or your array is 0.

You can initialize it in the constructor.

```
public NumRow(int numOfElementsOfDataSet) {
     this.i=numOfElementsOfDataSet;
     fatContent=new double[i];
     protienContent=new double[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help....It works although it shows the man and min value 0.0 but I will figure it out...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ui.UIAuxiliaryMethods;
```

In this line you attempt to use a class called 'ui'.  Do you have this class? If so please show us the code for it. Is 'ui' part of a library you're wanting to use, or is it a class you've written yourself?

```
UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput();
```

This line means you attempt to use a class called 'UIAuxiliaryMethods'. Do you have this class? If so please show us the code for it. Is 'UIAuxiliaryMethods' part of a library you're wanting to use, or is it a class you've written yourself?

Comment: UIAuxiliaryMehods.askUserForInput(); is included in a jar file which I was given and I had exported.
I am not sure how to show you code of this class because it is built in the library I had exported.
It basically ask for input file.

Comment: Can you link the jars you're using please? Or can you tell us the name of the library? It's easier for us to debug projects if we can compile the code. Saves us from having to manually work out which lines errors are occurring at, for example. It's good to have an SSCCE: if you make it easier for the people reading your question, I think you're more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Goerge but I am just trying to figure out how to upload the library or attach file to the question I have posted....
If you have any idea...Help would be appreciated..Thanks

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The link you posted works, although you still don't have an SSCCE here, but it looks like the question's been answered now anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot @George for your help.... :) 
I have got the answer...Thanks for trying to help me...

Comment: No problems. All the best!